# Gradle - compileTestGroovy can't resolve main Application class

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, dependency-injection, build

I have a strange issue. Our project has been up and running for 6 years now and some package upgrades were long overdue. 
App backend is written in Java 8, tests in Java and Groovy and frontend in AngularJS 1.5

App consists of 7 modules and whole project structure and build process is setup through gradle build files.

In the process of updating libraries versions biggest one was **mongodb** upgrade from  **4.0** and **spring** upgrade to **5.1.3** and **spring_boot** version from **1.2.6 to 2.1.1**.

I know, quite a few major upgrades and thanks to the all the tests we had I managed to change all our code to comply with the changes in new versions of the libraries. All tests are passing. Build of almost all the modules is working like a charm. **Except** for a module that consists of Groovy test classes. All the tests, when I run them from IntelliJ are passing, there are no compile or build errors.

But when I try running `gradle build` the task *testCompileGroovy* fails because the import in one of the abstract test specification classes can't be resolved. And it's the import of the main Application class that's needed for *classes* parameter of @SpringBootTest annotation.

Here is the libraries.gradle file with all libraries that we depend on defined...

```
ext {
spring_version = "5.1.3.RELEASE"
spring_boot_version = "2.1.1.RELEASE"
spring_data_mongodb = "2.1.3.RELEASE"
groovy_version = "2.4.5"

ext.lib = [

        spring_core                 : "org.springframework:spring-core:$spring_version",
        spring_context              : "org.springframework:spring-context:$spring_version",
        spring_context_support      : "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$spring_version",
        spring_test                 : "org.springframework:spring-test:$spring_version",
        spring_data_mongodb         : "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:$spring_data_mongodb",
        spring_shell                : "org.springframework.shell:spring-shell:1.1.0.RELEASE",
        spring_webmvc               : "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$spring_version",

        spring_web                  : "org.springframework:spring-web$spring_version",

        spring_boot_test            : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.1.1.RELEASE",

        spring_boot_starter         : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_starter_web     : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_starter_tomcat  : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_starter_security: "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_starter_test    : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_gradle_plugin   : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_autoconfigure   : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:$spring_boot_version",
        spring_boot_logging         : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-logging:$spring_boot_version",

        swager                      : "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1",
        swager_ui                   : "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1",

        groovy_all                  : "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovy_version",
        groovy_sql                  : dependencies.create("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:$groovy_version") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
        },

        http_builder                : "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1",
        httpmime                    : "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6",
        gmongo                      : dependencies.create("com.gmongo:gmongo:1.5") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
        },
        postgresql                  : "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41",
        bonecp                      : "com.jolbox:bonecp:0.8.0.RELEASE",
        joda_time                   : "joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2",
        guava                       : "com.google.guava:guava:18.0",
        gson                        : "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5",
        stripe                      : "com.stripe:stripe-java:1.37.0",
        jackson_annotations         : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.4",
        logentries                  : "com.logentries:logentries-appender:1.1.30",
        hibernate_validator         : "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.2.Final",
        logback_classic             : "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3",
        commons_lang                : "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1",
        commons_io                  : "commons-io:commons-io:2.4",
        commons_validator           : "commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0",
        httpclient                  : "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1",
        jasypt                      : "org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2",
        jsoup                       : "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3",
        trimou_core                 : "org.trimou:trimou-core:1.8.2.Final",
        jackson_core                : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8",
        jackson_databind            : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8",
        jackson_annotations         : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8",
        jackson_datatype_joda       : "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.9.8",
        google_api_services_gmail   : dependencies.create("com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev23-1.19.1") {
            exclude group: "com.google.guava"
        },
        google_http_client_jackson  : dependencies.create("com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.19.0") {
            exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
        },
        javax_mail                  : "com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.4",
        dnsjava                     : "dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7",
        email_reply_parser          : "./lib/EmailReplyParser-1.1.jar",
        salesforce                  : ["com.force.api:force-wsc:31.0.0", "com.force.api:force-partner-api:29.0.0", "com.force.api:force-metadata-api:29.0.0"],
        authy                       : 'com.authy:authy-java:1.1.0',
        libphonenumber              : 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.4',
        hellosign                   : 'com.hellosign:hellosign-java-sdk:4.0.5',
        awaitility                  : 'com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:1.7.0',


        junit                       : "junit:junit:4.12",
        hamcrest_all                : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3",
        hamcrest_core               : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3",
        mockito_core                : "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19",
        httpmime                    : "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6",
        rest_assured                : dependencies.create("com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.4.1") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
        },
        spock_core                  : "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4",
        spock_spring                : "org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.2-groovy-2.4",

        apache_pdf                  : "org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.4",
        google_cloud                : "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.35.0"
]}
```

And this is **build.gradle** file for the **tests-api** module that is failing.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':api')
    compile project(':cli')

    compile lib.groovy_all
    compile lib.http_builder
    compile lib.httpmime
    compile lib.gmongo
    compile lib.hamcrest_core

    testCompile lib.groovy_all
    testCompile lib.junit
    testCompile lib.spock_core
    testCompile lib.spock_spring
    testCompile lib.spring_boot_starter_test
}
```

**build.gradle** for **api** module looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release"
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath lib.spring_boot_gradle_plugin
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release"
    }
}

war {
    baseName = 'buyerdeck-api'
    version = '2.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':backend')
    compile project(':analytics')

    compile lib.spring_webmvc
    compile lib.spring_boot_starter
    compile lib.spring_boot_starter_web
    compile lib.spring_boot_starter_tomcat
    compile lib.spring_boot_starter_security
    compile lib.jackson_core
    compile lib.jackson_annotations
    compile lib.jackson_datatype_joda

    compile lib.swager
    compile lib.swager_ui
    testCompile lib.junit
    testCompile lib.hamcrest_all
    testCompile lib.mockito_core
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.buyerdeck.Application"
}
```

Aaaaand **build.gradle** of the **backend** module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release"
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: "groovy"
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':email')

    compile lib.spring_core
    compile lib.spring_context
    compile lib.spring_context_support
    compile lib.spring_data_mongodb

    compile lib.joda_time
    compile lib.guava
    compile lib.gson
    compile lib.stripe
    compile lib.jackson_core
    compile lib.jackson_databind
    compile lib.jackson_annotations
    compile lib.logentries
    compile lib.hibernate_validator
    compile lib.logback_classic
    compile lib.commons_lang
    compile lib.commons_io
    compile lib.commons_validator
    compile lib.httpclient
    compile lib.salesforce
    compile lib.jasypt
    compile lib.jsoup
    compile lib.trimou_core
    compile lib.hellosign
    compile lib.awaitility
    compile lib.authy
    compile lib.libphonenumber
    compile lib.httpmime
    compile lib.apache_pdf
    compile lib.google_cloud

    testCompile lib.spring_test
    testCompile lib.spring_boot_test
    testCompile lib.spring_boot_starter
    testCompile lib.junit
    testCompile lib.hamcrest_all
    testCompile lib.mockito_core
    testCompile lib.httpmime
    testCompile lib.rest_assured
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
            srcDir 'src/test-integration/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the class that's throwing the compilation error is ApiSpecification.groovy from **tests-api** module:

```
    package tests.api

import com.companyxyz.Application
import com.companyxyz.backend.core.tenant.Tenant
import com.companyxyz.backend.infrastructure.mongo.MongoSetup
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import spock.lang.Specification

@PropertySource("classpath:companyxyz.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = ["server.port:0", "mongo.database:companyxyz-test-api", "email.templates.root.path:../email-templates", "email.enabled:false", "timegate.enabled:true"])
abstract class ApiSpecification extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int serverPort

    @Value('${mongo.database}')
    private String dbName

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MongoSetup mongoSetup;

    private static boolean dbCleaned;

    def setup() {
        ApiSettings.apiUrl = "http://localhost:$serverPort/api/"
        ApiSettings.dbName = dbName

        println "apiurl $ApiSettings.apiUrl"
        if (!dbCleaned) {
            println "Dropping Mongo DB $dbName"
            mongoTemplate.getDb().drop();
            mongoSetup.ensureIndexes()
            dbCleaned = true;
        }
        DbExecutor.createMockThingies()
    }

    def removeUser(email) {
        mongoTemplate.remove(Query.query(Criteria.where("email").is(email)), com.companyxyz.backend.core.user.User.class)
    }


}
```

Error is at the line 3:

*import com.companyxyz.Application*

Can't resolve the import. testGroovyCompile task simply fails because of unresolved dependency. Running tests directly from classes that extend that class works without any issues.

Nothing in the *build.gradle* file for the module hasn't been changed except that one dependency, needed for spring tests was added, but everything else is the same as before. 
The module is dependent on other modules but their build files haven't changed much except for needed test dependencies.

I've spent hours and hours trying to tackle this but I just can't understand why it is not working. I tried with different gradle versions, without success. Does anyone have any idea what might be the cause to these problems?

Sorry for the long post, let me know if I can provide more info.

Luka

Comment: See my answer. I suggest you try solution 1) first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `api` module is a Spring Boot project: by default it will not produce a *standard* `jar` but only an *executable/fat* `jar` (or `war` if you have `war` plugin applied). 
Even if you add a 'project' dependency `compile project(':api')` in the `tests-api` module, Gradle won't be able to provide classes from `api` module to the classpath of `tests-api`, because there is no standard `jar` built from `api` module (see more details about project dependency type [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies)):

> A [Project] “lib” dependency is a special form of an execution dependency. It causes the other project to be built first and adds the jar with the classes of the other project to the classpath. It also adds the dependencies of the other project to the classpath.

So I see two options in order to solve your issue:

1) (*PREFERRED*) Configure SpringBoot plugin in `api` module to produce a standard `jar`

*build.gradle from api module*:

```
jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

See : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal

2) Create dependency from `tests-api` to `api` modules SourceSet:

*build.gradle from tests-api module*:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':api').sourceSets.main.output
    // others
}
```

(solution 2 should work, but not tested. Could cause error with `api` project dependencies not available in `tests-api` module)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I actually got it working yesterday with the second option, just after posting the question. But it seemed like a hack. I will definitely try the the first option as well and accept your answer. 
What troubled me the most is that previously project was building with same scripts without issues. I thought *war* task provided the same output as jar plus some. I will definitely read more into depth of gradle build tasks.
Thanks again for your help